# php_mongo extension is installed, but how come rockmongo still not connected?

Tags: php, mongodb, wamp

I have a wamp server. I also have mongodb installed. I have installed the php_mongo extension, make changes in php.ini. I downloaded rockmongo, unzipped the file in my www folder. I edited the config file but when I try to open the GUI, it says:

**"To make things right, you must install php_mongo module. Here for installation documents on PHP.net."**

Need help. thanks

Comment: Have you restarted WAMP ?

Comment: Also, does the output of phpinfo() actually show the MongoDB extension? There are several different binaries in the download package, and you absolutely have to pick the right one.

Comment: I have this problem too. I do see the mongodb driver in phpinfo() but ROckMongo isn't working.

Comment: mine is working now, turned out that i have to choose the thread safe version 5.3 because my php version is also 5.3

Answer (score 2):

Hi I also had the same problem. I just solved it by following these steps.

Just install the mongodb Driver extension  via `sudo pecl install mongo`

After installation check mongodb Driver is found or not via `sudo pecl search mongo`

If it is installed successfully following output will come

```
ubuntu@ip-***-3*-*-**:~$ sudo pecl search mongo
Retrieving data...0%
Matched packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=======================================
Package Stable/(Latest) Local
mongo   1.4.2 (stable)  1.4.2 MongoDB database driver
```

change php.ini located under /etc/php5/apache2

Add this line under Dynamic Extension of php.ini `extension=mongo.so` save the file

Now restart your server via `sudo service apache2 restart`

It will work

Comment: When i tried localhost/rockmongo, I got a blank page with a console error "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/rockmongo/" . Any idea?

Comment: hi, `sudo pecl install mongo` would nort work in php 7.0

Comment: brew install php70-mongodb for php 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Quite old post, but for those who still find for a solution like me.
It's solved by:
- php_mongo-1.4.5-5.3-vc9.dll 
- WampServer 2.2
- PHP 5.3.18

Windows 7, 64 bit.

PHP_Mongo here (https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/php_mongo-1.4.5.zip)