# To make things right, you must install php_mongo module

Tags: mongodb, centos, plesk, php-mongodb

I am not able to install the php mongo driver in a VPS. I've followed [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) documentantion

I checked this stack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438099/php-mongo-extension-is-installed-but-how-come-rockmongo-still-not-connected) but i can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

The VPS runs on PLESK 12 and CentOS 7.

lets say that I have the domain "mydomain.com" on my plesk and in mydomain.com/info.php a phpinfo script.

PHP INFO

[image: php info]

[image: php info 2]

PHP.ini

[image: php ini]

[image: modules]

What amb I doing wrong?

The weird thing is that when I run the command "php -v" I get this output:

[image: php version]

Which is not the version that is showing phpInfo.

Finally, I can't install the newest driver versions using pecl because I get the following error:

[image: pecl error]

I would appreciate any help

Thanks!!

Comment: No one knows what can I do? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's happens because you are call native OS binaries of `php` and `pecl`.

Plesk's PHP ***5.6*** binaries are stored in `/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/`. So you have to call /opt/plesk/php/**5.6**/bin/php and /opt/plesk/php/**5.6**/bin/pecl

***Here full steps how to install mongodb for PHP 5.6:***

[root@cos71x64-plesk12 ~]# /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/pecl install mongodb

```
/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/phpize not found. Run 'yum install plesk-php56-devel' to install it
```

[root@cos71x64-plesk12 ~]# yum install plesk-php56-devel

[root@cos71x64-plesk12 ~]# /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/pecl install mongodb

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/opt/plesk/php/5.6/lib64/php/modules/mongodb.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mongodb-1.1.4
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=mongodb.so" to php.ini
```

[root@cos71x64-plesk12 ~]# echo "extension=mongodb.so" > /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.d/mongodb.ini

[root@cos71x64-plesk12 ~]# /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php --info | grep mongo

```
/opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.d/mongodb.ini,
mongodb
mongodb support => enabled
mongodb version => 1.1.4
mongodb stability => stable
libmongoc version => 1.3.3
mongodb.debug => no value => no value
```

Comment: Apologizes for the delay. I'he been out some days... Your solution works perfect. Thank you very much!